# If using radio buttons, do I need to save the file as macro enabled?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, microsoft-word-2010

I have this .docx document in which I inserted some radio buttons.

[image]

And each time I save the document I get this message.

[image]

And I choose 'Yes' every time because as far as I know I'm not using any macro just some radio buttons. Is this OK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is OK. Sorry I don't have a reference for this, other than experience.

Radio buttons are ActiveX controls. When you insert them, Word assumes these are being used as part of a macro to process the data selections being made by the user. Therefore, you get the `VBA Project` warning.

If you are not using any macro (VBA) in the document, you are safe to save as a macro-free document.

It may go without saying, in the event you were using macros and you chose the macro-free option, the macros would not work.